# scatter plot markers different colors based on value

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have two columns of the data frame. One column indicates the CPU node and the other indicates the threshold. I need to plot a scatter plot for that data frame. My question is how to get different colors on the threshold column. For example, 0-25% green, 25-50% light green, 50-75% yellow and above 75% red. As of now, I am getting only a single color.

Below is the data frame

```
cpu node  threshold
node 1      20
node 2      30
node 3      50
node 4      59
node 5      65
node 6      95
```

code for this I have written:

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(mode="markers", x=cpu node, y=threshold, marker_symbol='triangle-up',
                           marker_line_color="midnightblue", marker_color="lightskyblue",
                           marker_line_width=2, marker_size=15,
                           hovertemplate=cpu node))
```

[image]
The above is giving only a single color with triangle markers.

Can anyone tell me how to get the graph that looks like this with customized colors i.e; **['green', 'light green', 'yellow', 'red']** based on the range of values
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, set the marker color to the value of the y-axis.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(mode="markers", x=df['cpu node'], y=df['threshold'], marker_symbol='triangle-up',
                           marker_line_color="midnightblue", marker_color=df['threshold'],
                           marker_line_width=2, marker_size=15,
                           hovertemplate=df['cpu node']))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to get customized colors based on threshold range values? For example green, light green, yellow, and red?

Comment: You can do this by using marker_color to specify the color of your choice in a one-to-one relationship with the data.

Comment: `marker_color=['green','yellow','blue','red','red','red']`In this way, you can specify the color names that can be used in plotly for the number of data.

Comment: See [this page](https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/#color-scale-for-scatter-plots-with-graph-objects/).Then you can use the color scale to specify continuous colors.